# How to give an app permission to write to external SD on a rooted phone

Tags: root-access, external-sd

I have a rooted Galaxy S7.  I'd like to give permission to an app that does not request it to write to the external SD card storage.  How can I do this?

Comment: did you try: `pm grant` command?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the app package name, you can try the shell command `pm grant`.

Enable USB Debugging, probably already done for you, then type `adb shell pm grant [replace_app.package.name] android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` hit enter. Your app should now have that permission.  Not sure if permanently though.

Comment: Googled and figured out how to turn on USB debugging. Type where????

Comment: You need a terminal to be able to run adb commands. google again to know how to get adb running on your computer